# How can I set the maximum draw type for multiple objects?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, draw-mode

I'm currently working on a scene containing 1000+ objects which all need to be set to a different draw type to save on computationally expenses in the viewport. But doing this for every object separately is really tedious.

Therefor I'm wondering if there's a way to change the maximum draw type of multiple objects simultaneously. Preferably only the selected objects.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just right click on the "maximum draw type" list and choose the "copy to selected" option:

[image]

Note: this function is available in many contexts (not all).

Additional information:

As said [Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) in the comments, you can use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key whilst clicking on/choosing the wanted 'maximum draw type'. And that will apply it to all selected objects without using the menu indicated above.

But this <kbd>Alt</kbd> key won't work here if you have the 'Emulate 3 Buttons Mouse' in the user preferences (which allows to use the alt key to replace the middle button features, if you are using a track pad for instance).

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! I totally forgot about this feature.
I now have my scene optimized in a couple of seconds instead of the expected hours!

Comment: You can also keep Alt key pressed while changing values to apply to all selection

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, you're right. Just for information, if you have 'emulate 3 buttons mouse' in your settings (as I have) this will not work (as 'alt' is unavailable because of that).

Comment: Didn't know that,never used *Emulate 3 Buttons Mouse* feature myself, but nice to know. Maybe add those to your answer as well.